# Importerror: No module named memcache (Django project)

Tags: python, django, memcached

In a Django project of mine, I run this command to run the project on localhost:

`python manage.py runserver`

It results in the error:

`Importerror: No module named memcache`

However, I've already fulfilled the requirement via: `sudo apt-get install python-memcache`

Peculiarly, if I go into the python shell outside my virtualevn and try `import memcache`, it works fine. However, inside my virtualenv, if I go into the python shell and try `import memcache`, I get the same import error listed above. What's going on?

Comment: You might have two versions installed, and your app doesn't run with the default one.

Comment: Possible. Any suggestions on how do I start debugging this?

Comment: run `python --version` to check your default Python interpreter. Check the first line of your app main script (if you don't know where is it, just call `which <app_name>`

Comment: You are using `virtualenv` to run this application?.. if so, just do `pip install memcache` from inside your venv and try to import/run it again.

Comment: That worked. To be exact, I did `pip install python-memcached` (notice the d). If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As you are using `virtualenv` you'd need to install this dependency from inside as you might have created the virtual environment before installed it as a system-wide library.

After activate your `virtualenv` type:

```
pip install python-memcached
```

This should solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on pymemcache  [documentation](https://github.com/pinterest/pymemcache)

> Since version 3.2, Django has included a pymemcache-based cache backend. See its documentation.
> On older Django versions, you can use django-pymemcache.

So for Django 3.2+ use :

```bash
pip install pymemcache
```

Answer (score 1):

First
run

```
pip install django-pylibmc
```

set you cache backend:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1.11211',
    }
}
```